# Undefined cols in row after [saveEventually]

Tags: ios, parse-platform

When I save data on parse cloud, object like: saveEventually without internet connection, then close app, after relaunch app in parse cloud created new row, but all fields are undefined.

This is bug or I do something wrong?

```
     [newItem pinInBackgroundWithName:@"PurchaseItems" block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            [newItem saveEventually];
        }];
```

Comment: I can't duplicate your results, works for me.

Comment: it means i can't duplicate it not working. It works for me

Comment: Close app - that mean unload from memory fully, not minimize to background. Please check again.

Comment: I understood completely. Works for me. Are you relaunching the app with internet or with network off?

Comment: I am checking now, in both cases all cols undefined, except date createAt, updatedAt, ALC